# facebook sharing from iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

In my iphone app i am accessing my facebook info and sending it to the server. From server facebook sharing should happen
I have created my app in FB and while clicking sync button i am able to go to the FB login page.After loged in it asks for the authentication

But it just asking for "basic info" not for public sharing etc (i have included that in my FB app)

```
 -(IBAction)fbConnect:(id)sender{

    flag = 1;
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

  if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

    [self updateView];
  } else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        [self updateView];
    }];
   }


  NSLog(@"string issss %@",string);


   }

    - (void)updateView {
      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
      if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {

        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              appDelegate.session.accessToken];

        NSLog(@"string issss %@",string);
         NSString *urlstrng;
        if(flag == 1){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",string];
          [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
     }
     if(flag == 2){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends? access_token=%@",string];
        [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
    }


     } else {

    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              appDelegate.session.accessToken];
    NSString *urlstrng;
    if(flag == 1){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@",string];
        [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
        }

    if(flag == 2){
        urlstrng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@",string];
        [self dataFetching:urlstrng];
    }


        }
     }

      -(void)dataFetching:(NSString*)strng1{

      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strng1];
       ProfileConnector *obj = [[ProfileConnector alloc] init];
       obj.delegate1 = self;
       [obj parsingJson:url];

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are not requesting extra items through your code. You can do it by using openSessionWithAllowLoginUI.

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"email",
                        nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
```

}

Comment: i am getting an error here - [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];

Comment: In your appdelegate. I believe you are using FacebookSDK. right?